# How to turn categories recorded in a single column into multiple columns for each category

Tags: r

Say I have a table like this

```
year  genre
1992  comedy
2012  comedy
2007  drama
1998  drama
2005  drama
2001  romance
2013  documentary
...   ....
```

How can I change it to something like this

```
comedy drama romance documentary
1992   2007   2001      2013
2012   1998   ...       ...
...    ...    ...        
...           ...
              ...
```

the results for year in each genre are DIFFERENT in length

Comment: What you have tried? As written your question is too broad for SO and you'll get more help if you show us that you've tried something.

Comment: Have a look at `tidyr::spread` or `reshape2::dcast` if you're using R. If you're using mysql look up `pivot`.

Comment: Your example begs the question, what is the meaning of a row in your desired output? Why is the drama column 2007 then 1998 instead of 1998 then 2007? Normally a transformation like this has an ID that is repeated in the long form and turns into a single row identifier in the wide version.

Comment: @RichardErickson I tried to split them by genres in r, it returns me similar results with each genre containing 2 columns as years and the genres repeating next to years

Comment: @Gregor, sorry for any confusion I made. my desired year values doesnt have to be ordered is what i'm trying to say.

Comment: Please consider posting what you've tired and why it didn't work. This and other tips may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In your example your data turns out to be rectangular - you have the same number of years for each genre. Are you sure this is true?

Comment: @Gregor, oops, that's not true, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3):

With unbalanced groups (different lengths), I think you're better off getting a list where each item is a vector of years for the corresponding genre. This is easy with `split`

```
genre_list = split(your_data$year, your_data$genre)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% group_by(genre) %>%
        mutate(num = row_number()) %>%
        spread(genre, year)

Source: local data frame [3 x 5]

    num comedy documentary drama romance
  (int)  (int)       (int) (int)   (int)
1     1   1992        2013  2007    2001
2     2   2012          NA  1998      NA
3     3     NA          NA  2005      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Or we can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dat)[, num:= seq_len(.N), genre], num~genre, value.var='year')
```